# How to connect to remote MBean Server in Spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, jmx

I would like monitor my Spring integration Server which is running on a remote machine using MBeans.
I added the following to the spring context file.

```
<context:mbean-server />
<int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="spring.application" />
```

This should enable viewing the MBean information such as MessageCount, Running status etc. using VisualVM. 
I am not sure how to connect to the MBean server remotely.

VisualVM has two ways of connecting to Remote JMX Server.
hostname:port  or
service:jmx::

Is there a default port that MBeanServer runs on? 
does the  make the MBean access remotely? Is there anything that needs to be done to access MBeans remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMX uses a JSR-160 connector, using RMI which is not particularly firewall-friendly.

You also need to enable remote access, including a port; see the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html).

Spring provides supporting classes to allow you to access MBeans in another spring app [see the Spring JMX documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-jsr160).

Finally, you can consider using something like [jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) as an alternative to JSR-160, exposing your MBeans over HTTP.